# php: how to: echo "<input value='{$test}'>"; with $test=" (亜) (') (\") ";?

Tags: php, html, utf-8, quotes

```
<?php
$info = " 亜 and ' and \" ";
$info=str_replace(array("'","\""),array("&#39;","&#34;"),$info);
echo "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>";
echo "<input id=info name=info value='{$info}' >";
?>
```

This works, **BUT**: Is there a tidier method like `$info=htmlentities($info,ENT_QUOTES)` which **preserves** the **UTF-8** display? (htmlentities **doesn't**)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify third `utf-8` parameter:

```
$info = htmlentities($info, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

**From Docs:**

> Like htmlspecialchars(), it takes an
>   optional third argument charset which
>   defines character set used in
>   conversion. Presently, the ISO-8859-1
>   character set is used as the default.

**Source:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php